# Only root-permissions to USB-drive after formatting with Gparted

Tags: usb-drive, automount

I formatted my external USB-drive with GParted to ext2 file system. After that the usb-drive is automounted with root-permission and now I only can write with `sudo` to the drive. Of course I can change the permissions manually with `chmod`, but the behavior I want is that by inserting the drive it gets automounted with permission 7 independent of which user is logged in, like an usual usb-drive does.
I hope my question is clear enough, if not I'll clarify, just ask me.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Try opening nautilus in root, look in /media for the drive, and see if you can change permissions that way.

Comment: Try to format it again with Disk Utility.

Comment: Dis Utility was a good tip, thx. Now I have r/w access. Anyway if I'm logged in as another user I still cannot cp to this disk. ???