# How can I change permissions on external drives right after formatting with GParted?

Tags: permissions, gparted, ext4

Using **GParted**, I have formatted an external HDD to ext4.

As it turns out the default is that I have no write access.

How can I change permissions on external drives?

Comment: For what it's worth, this seems to be a problem with ext4 (no idea why). If you format it to fa32, for instance, gparted will give it normal user access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that you may have formatted the drive with root privileges.

If so see link below for some possible solutions.

[Only root-permissions to USB-drive after formatting with Gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/200984/only-root-permissions-to-usb-drive-after-formatting-with-gparted)

Hope it helps.

Comment: The question linked here doesn't actually have any answers. The one linked up in the "already answered" box does however, and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/277314/969327) worked for me. Yay!